# Windowsでキーボードレイアウトを英語配列にしたい、という質問はオフトピックでしょうか？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

[Windows 10でキーボードレイアウトを英語配列に設定したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/26934/windows-10%E3%81%A7%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AB%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

この質問は過去2回クローズレビューが行われ、合計10人の方が投票されましたが、2回とも僅差でオープンのままにするという結果になっています。

プログラムには関係ないからオフトピック、開発環境の構築ということでオントピック、といった意見が既にコメント欄に挙がっていますが、他の方々から見た印象はいかがでしょうか？
<sub>※別に白黒つけたいわけではなく、この手の質問についてどう思われているのだろう、という程度の質問です。</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> 日本語環境なのに英語キーボードを使うのはプログラマくらいですから、プログラミング環境構築に関する質問ということでよいと思います。

という @mjy さんのコメントと同じような理由で、オントピックだと考え投票しました。

プログラミングを行う際には、キーボードの設定を変えるのは、いくつかの環境ではほぼ必要不可欠な作業だと認識しています。(例えば、Caps lock と Ctrl の入れ替えとか。。)

その延長線上の質問だと考えて、オントピック票を投じました。

Answer (score 2):

/help/on-topic をよく読んでみると

- プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題である
- ソフトウェア開発に固有の、実際的で回答可能な問題である

ソフトウェアでは無いですが、よく使うという点では良いと思います。

---

**オフトピックだと思っていたとき**
この質問はスタックオーバーフローというよりsuper userの方が良い気がします。
日本語版が登場していないので仕方がないと思いますが、プログラミングには関係ないと思いますのでオフトピックです。
コメントには、

> 英語キーボードを使うのはプログラマくらいですから

とありますが、そうとも限らないと思います。
といってもほとんどプログラマしか使いませんが。